# How to set variables from withCredentials as global variables in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scripted pipeline where I would like to take the variables from withCredentials and set them as global variables. I've tried the following and in a bat command if I run "set PASSWORD" it returns

"USERNAMEx=****"

"USERNAME=****"

However, a further step using the Allure plugin fails with:

"Required property not found: ALLURE_JIRA_USERNAME"

If I set the values as parameters the environment variables are recognised by the plugin. Ideally I would like to use the withCredentials though.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dsdsdsdd',
    passwordVariable: 'PASSWORDx',
    usernameVariable: 'USERNAMEx')]) {
node('master'){
    withEnv([
        PASSWORD = "${PASSWORDx}",
        USERNAME = "${USERNAMEx}"
    ]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the variable value to global variable `env` inside `withCredentials`

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
    credentialsId: 'dsdsdsdd',
    passwordVariable: 'USERNAMEx',
    usernameVariable: 'USERNAMEx')
]) {

    env.USERNAMEx = "${USERNAMEx}"
    env.USERNAMEx = "${USERNAMEx}"
}

//access variable outside of withCredentials via global variable `env`

echo env.USERNAMEx
echo "${env.USERNAMEx}"
echo "${USERNAMEx}"
```

Comment: Doesn't work: throws an error at `env....` `Expected a step...`